# how to configure environment for elixir shell such alias command when starting?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

When using elixir shell, I always have to copy the code like following to shell terminal from `ms word` doc.

```
alias Mirror.Repo
alias Mirror.Imports.Importer
```

In erlang, I have write these code in the .erlang script file.

How to do it for elixir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it in an [`.iex.exs` file](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/main/IEx.html#module-the-iex-exs-file) at the root of your mix project.

This is convenient for:

- aliases and imports
- configure inspect options

This [article](https://samuelmullen.com/articles/customizing_elixirs_iex/) provides some helpful examples.

Comment: It works now. Thank you very much. Now I don't need copy code from word doc to console anymore, It saves a lot of time.